# Intellij Idea - update and project migration, how to?

Tags: intellij-idea

Am I right that after Idea update I can just open my old projects without any risk,
or there is any migration procedure?

And what in opposite direction: Is it safe to open Idea projects created or used by higher IDE version with older IDE?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right that after Idea update I can just open my old projects without any risk, or there is any migration procedure?

If there are any incompatible changes in the project file format, IDEA will convert the project files automatically and backup the older versions.

> And what in opposite direction: Is it safe to open Idea projects created or used by higher IDE version with older IDE?

Project files are not backwards compatible, it's not recommended to open projects from the new IDE version in older versions.